# Testing React JS dropdown with Selenium and java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, reactjs

I have a drop down, that populates values dynamically using React JS.
How can I select a value from this dropdown. Can you point me in the right direction maybe with an example.

here is the HTML code for the page....
The Div that contains the "Year" text is the dropdown. As soon as I click on the Year, it gives me few options like 2015,2014,2013 etc. But I am not sure how to access these values using Selenium.

```html
<div class="fitment-box__first-select" data-reactid=".2.0.0.0.0.2.1"><span data-reactid=".2.0.0.0.0.2.1.0">My vehicle was made in</span><div class="Select fitment-box__select-year" data-reactid=".2.0.0.0.0.2.1.1"><input type="hidden" name="year" value="" data-reactid=".2.0.0.0.0.2.1.1.0"><div class="Select-control" data-reactid=".2.0.0.0.0.2.1.1.1"><div class="Select-placeholder" data-reactid=".2.0.0.0.0.2.1.1.1.0:$placeholder">Year</div><div class="Select-input " tabindex="0" data-reactid=".2.0.0.0.0.2.1.1.1.1">&nbsp;</div><span class="Select-arrow-zone" data-reactid=".2.0.0.0.0.2.1.1.1.4"><span class="Select-arrow" data-reactid=".2.0.0.0.0.2.1.1.1.4.0"></span></span></div></div></div>
```

Comment: I don't know where to start. I used Select webelement from Selenium but it doesnt work.

Comment: The Select won't work because there is no such <Select></Select> in my React project. And the Actions won't work too because this statment act.click(elementValue).build().perform(); wont accept a String of elementValue, it has to be a WebElment type. However, the value dropdown list is not a WebElement. I'm searching for answer too...

Comment: @Sam - Did you find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue and found a solution based on Saurabh's answer.

```
WebElement button = driver.findElement(element);

Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(button).click().build().perform();
```

Answer (score -1):

Use action class. 
Here is an example:

```
Actions act = new Actions(this.getDriver());
act.moveToElement(element).click().build().perform();
act.click(elementValue).build().perform();
```

Answer (score -1):

The standard selenium dropdown method has been working for me. There are other options such as selecting by index too if you don't care what year you are picking.

```
Select dropdown = new Select(element)); 
dropdown.selectByVisibleText(year);
```

Comment: The Select tag won't work because there is no such <Select></Select> tag in given HTML