# Select value from ReactJS dropdown with Selenium Java

Tags: reactjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver

We have ReactJS front end application which has dropdown box, when clicked it shows elements inside it and need to select the checkbox(s), however if try to inspect the dropdown values, it shows attribute which goes off if clicked somewhere.

Below is the html:

```
<div class="MuiFormControl-root fullWidth">

<div class="MuiInputBase-root MuiOutlinedInput-root adornedEnd">

<input aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="off" id="checkboxes-tags-demo" placeholder="Select" type="text" class="MuiInputBase-input inputAdornedEnd" aria-autocomplete="list" autocapitalize="none" spellcheck="false" value="">
```

Tried below ways: But it is not working, getting no such element exception

```
List<WebElement> countries = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='MuiFormControl-root MuiTextField-root MuiFormControl-fullWidth']/div"));
            for(WebElement tag : countries){
            if(tag.getText().trim().equals("TITLE"))
            tag.click();
            }
```

Gone through the thread:
[Testing React JS dropdown with Selenium and java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36776127/testing-react-js-dropdown-with-selenium-and-java)

Please guide.

Comment: Is it a public url?

Answer (score 0):

Could solve the issue by following below steps:

1. Click the dropdown's arrow mark (^) to expand the Dropdown
2. Then user sendKeys arrow down/up in the input element of the dropdown> then ENTER key to select the value
3. Tab out from the field

driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@alt='Expand'])[1]")).click();

```
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='tags']")).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
            System.out.println("clicking arrow down");
            sleep(5);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='tags']")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
            System.out.println("clicked enter");
            sleep(2);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='tags']")).sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
            System.out.println("tabbed out");
```

Answer (score 0):

Has success using following selectors for MUI Select:

```
// Using Selenide
var selectRole = $("#my-select");
selectRole.click();
sleep(1000);
$("li[data-value='" + desiredValue + "']").click();
```